# How do I find the area bounded by a $y=\frac{4}{3}x^2+\frac{12}{3}x-3$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves

I am having difficulties with this problem:$y=\frac{4}{3}x^2+\frac{12}{3}x-3$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$.
Graphng two of the functions I get the following:
[image]
Graphing both functions shows that they intersect at $x=0.771$.
Now, the thing thats bugging me about this problem is that both graph's don't seem to have a bounded area. For this particular situation, $y=\sqrt{x}$ is only valid for values that are positive only. 
I took a rough guess and did the integral like this:
$$\int_{0}^{0.771}(\sqrt{x})-(\frac{4}{3}x^2+\frac{12}{3}x-3)$$
$$\int_{0}^{0.771}(\sqrt{x})-\frac{4}{3}x^2-\frac{12}{3}x+3)$$
$$\int\sqrt{x}-\frac{4}{3}\int(x^2)-\frac{12}{3}\int(x)+\int(3)$$
$$\frac{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3/2}-\frac{4x^3}{9}-\frac{12x^2}{6}+3x$$
Evaluating the integral:
$$[\frac{(0.771)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3/2})-\frac{4(0.771)^3}{9}-\frac{12(0.771)^2}{6}+3(0.771)]^{0.771}-[0]^{0}$$
$$\therefore \int_{0}^{0.771}(\sqrt{x})-(\frac{4}{3}x^2+\frac{12}{3}x-3)=0.9204 \text{square units}$$

I don't know if my approach is correct. I need help.

Comment: @joseabp91 Oh righto. So the bounded area is that tiny little portion of the graph from x=0 to x=0.771 right?

Comment: Does the problem say $y = \sqrt{x}$ or $x = y^2$, because it makes a difference

Comment: @caverac problem says $y=\sqrt{x}$. Am I allowed to rearrange it to that?

Comment: The thing here is that $y = \color{red}{+}\sqrt{x}$ is only one of the solutions of $y^2 = x$ (your blue line above), but there's another one, namely $y = \color{red}{-}\sqrt{x}$ which will completely close the region. I would have interpreted the problem like that, because as it is right now it is a bit ambiguous (as you rightly noticed). But that's just my opinion

Comment: Yes because the function which you want to integrate is just positive between $0$ and $0.771$. The final solution must be $1.37$.